# Best Way to Include HTML pages inside HTML pages (for performance)

Tags: javascript, php, html, performance

What would be best performance wise for including small HTML files inside a large HTMl page.

What I am considering are:

1. PHP's include() to put the HTML onto the page directly.
2. Javascripts XMLHttpRequest() to load the page and put the response in the innerHTML of a div.

I know the JS will be client side so take some of the load off the server right?

But then it loads after the page is already on the screen which can be awkward.

Any opinions or thoughts?

Comment: The JS will be client side, but the extra HTTP requests it sends won't be. Your #2 will be worse in basically every way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends what you are trying to accomplish. If you don't *need* (and this is largely something only you can quantify unless you write us an essay about your project) to load stuff with a client-side network request (need would be something like comments, notifications, etc.), then you shouldn't be putting that on the client.

In fact, you generally shouldn't be thinking about saving server resources in that manner. Phones or older computers don't necessarily have the resources or bandwidth to spare that a privileged developer might have.

That being said, many modern front-end MVC frameworks (React, Vue.js) generally place much more load on the client from rendering to network requests, but that's a story for another time. (Plus, they do lots of different optimizations that would take more explaning than this answer could fit or that my brain cells could process.)

If you're just making this consideration for the sake of considering, don't. Do as much processing as possible server side, especially with the assumption that your application is primarily PHP-based. So yes, include. Your users will thank you for it.

--

Oh, P.S. There's a good chance you'll end up giving your server more load (albeit minimal in the grand scheme of things) by making extra network requests from a client end. That's extra stuff your server has to process, think of refreshing your page once vs. refreshing it multiple times. So there's that, too. Hope this exposé helped a bit.